# How do I generate the copyright symbol in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have ruby build file that we used to read the assembly attributes that we use in our application

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9 and higher:

```
"\u00A9"
```

Comment: Or `"\xA9"` or `"\251"` in 1.8.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for `&copy;` which displays as the copyright symbol in HTML?

Comment: Yes, but it wouldn't display it in a string in ERB; for example `<%= link_to "&copy; ...", some_path %>` will html-escape the string

Answer (score 0):

```
"\xC2\xA9".force_encoding('UTF-8')
```